# Google Maps API V2 (Android) authentication erro

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm quite new to Android (and specifically Android Studio) development.

I tried to read several discussions of people with the same problem of mine.

I have followed 2 times the whole tutorial at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
(with the only exception I didn't create a empty application but with a maps view)

I even tried to generate SHA1 various times

- with different keystores
- both debug and release types
- tried to put API key directly as string or with reference to google_maps_api.xml in "values" folder.

as well as

- regenerating API key
- make a new project following again the whole procedure.

But I keep getting the error:

```
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors)
```

both on device (Nexus 5) and emulator AVD (Nexus 5).

Thanks in advance for any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple cause,

first,

1. try to uninstall the app from your device
2. Clean the project
3. Install the project 
   It worked for me once,

if it doesn't work,

check that

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>
```

then check that `<meta-data>` is set correctlly in `<application>` tag.

Also try by adding following Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Comment: somehow the problem was that I was using the wrong SHA-1 (which I extracted using Google's guidelines). But then I used the SHA-1 shown in error console in Android Studio (which was somehow different) and it worked flawlessly